# zend framework 1.12 robots.txt

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, robots.txt

I have created a robots.txt file containing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This robots.txt file has been put in the below directory:

```
wwwsite/application
wwwsite/library
wwwsite/ZendFramework-1.10.7.tar.gz
wwwsite/public
.
|--- captcha
|
|--- css
|--- js
|--- img
|--- files
|
.htaccess
index.php
robots.txt
```

It doesn't seem to like this as when I visit www.site.com/robots.txt, I still get error message saying "Message: Resource 'robots.txt' not found"

**** Update ****
My .htaccess file looks like:

```
php_value "short_open_tag" "on"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Is there a way to ignore the zend mvc approach and just use like a redirect within Apache? So that when mysite.com/robots.txt gets called it directs to /robotx.txt?

Comment: What's in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Tim Fountain, I have updated the op.

Comment: If it's in the `public` folder, it should be fine. Perhaps perms on that file are such that the web server process cannot read it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It seems that the file has the correct permissions. I have checked and the permissons of the robots.txt file has permissions as follows:

-rw-r--r--